# Is transition map the identity operator?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(U_1,\phi_1),(U_2,\phi_2)$ be charts of a differentiable manifold $M$.

**Question:**

$D\phi_2(\phi_1^{-1}(0))\circ D\phi_1^{-1}(0)=\Bbb{I}$, where $\Bbb{I}$ is the identity operator.

is this statement true? If yes, how can I prove it?

**Context:**

There is a statement in the differential geometry which claims that the definition of tangent curves with respect to a chart $\phi$ is independent of chart choice.

The proof looks the following way:

Let $c_1,c_2$ be curves, they are tangent with respect to $\phi_1$ iff $D(\phi_1 \circ c_1)=D(\phi_1 \circ c_2)$

$\phi_1 \circ c_i=(\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}) \circ \phi_1 \circ c_i \Rightarrow D((\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}) \circ \phi_1 \circ c_i)(0)=D\phi_2(c_1(0)) \circ D\phi_1^{-1}((\phi_1 \circ c_i)(0)) \circ D(\phi_1 \circ c_i)(0) \stackrel{?}{=} D(\phi_1 \circ c_i)(0) \Rightarrow D(\phi_1 \circ c_i)=D(\phi_2 \circ c_i)$

I suppose that this relation is held when $D\phi_2(c_1(0)) \circ D\phi_1^{-1}((\phi_1 \circ c_i)(0))=\Bbb{I}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you want to show is not true in general and also not needed.

Recall that we say that two smooth curves $c_1,c_2:I\to M$ with $c_1(0)=p=c_2(0)$ are tangential at $p\in M$ if $(\phi\circ c_1)'(0) = (\phi\circ c_2)'(0)$ for some chart $(\phi,U)$ around $p$.

To show that this is independent of charts, consider another chart $(\psi,U)$ around $p$. Then the proof is just an application of the chain rule, similar to what you wrote above

$$(\psi\circ c_1)'(0)=(\psi\circ\phi^{-1}\circ \phi \circ c_1)'(0) = 
D(\psi\circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))\,(\phi\circ c_1)'(0)$$

Now we use that $c_1,c_2$ are tangential at $p$ *with respect to* $\phi$, i.e. $(\phi\circ c_1)'(0) = (\phi\circ c_2)'(0)$ and we obtain

$$D(\psi\circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))\,(\phi\circ c_1)'(0)=D(\psi\circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))\,(\phi\circ c_2)'(0) =\dots= (\psi\circ c_2)'(0)$$

where "$\dots$" just is the same application of the chain rule as in the line before but just backwards.

Comment: So how did this show independence of charts if we just obtain the condition of tangency with respect to $\psi$? I believe, we want to show $D(\psi \circ c_1)(0)=D(\phi \circ c_1)(0)$, don't we?

Comment: @ВладимирСавин Because $\psi$ was an arbitrary chart around $p$. So what we have shown is that if $c_1,c_2$ are tangential at $p$ wrt some chart, then they are also tangential wrt any chart around $p$. Meaning the notion is independent of a specific choice of charts.

Comment: @ВладимирСавин The condition that you mention is not what we want, since the Jacobian of the local expressions $\psi\circ c_1$ or $\phi\circ c_1$ don't have to be equal. We are using different coordinates after all.

Comment: got it. Thank you